# Writing a Perl Wrapper for C library

Tags: perl

I have a C library and I need to access its functions in a Perl program.

I researched this on the internet and find that this wrapper can be implemented using XS, but I saw that XS is not consistent if needed to run the code on different OS.

I also found module FFI::Raw on CPAN which might do the job. Does anyone use FFI::Raw in production? What do you suggest to use, FFI::Raw or XS?

Comment: If FFI::Raw works for you, it's definitely easier to use it than to write your own version! Otherwise, you will have to use XS (like FFI::Raw does).

Comment: Does FFI::RAW enougth to write such code or to use XS ,the code will be run on production system, what could be problems which I will face with FFI::RAW and XS solve it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that last comment.

Comment: I ask what the advantages of using XS over FFI::RAW ,and if there are some cases which could not be solved with FFI::RAW ?

Comment: 1) It's FFI::Raw. 2) Like I already said, FFI::Raw uses XS. There it's no choice but to use XS. XS is how you tell Perl how to interface with C functions. The choice is between FFI::Raw (which uses XS) and writing your own module (which uses XS).

Comment: If you don't want to use libffi, and you don't want to use raw XS, another option is [Inline::C](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/SISYPHUS/Inline-0.53/C/C.pod) which makes doing a lot of XS stuff easy without having to actually write any XS.

Comment: Did you try SWIG (http://www.swig.org/papers/Perl98/swigperl.htm) ?